# Encoding::Undefined: ConversionError at / "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, ascii, sprockets

I've been trying to update from Sprockets 3 to Sprockets 4 but I'm getting the following error: `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError at / "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`

The error happens in the following line: `<%= javascript_include_tag "c/components/App", "data-turbolinks-track" => 'reload' %>` and I can't understand why.

Comment: What version of rails are you running? Can you post a full stack trace of the error?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the JS? The encoding errors are usually that some text in the file is not using UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with Rails 4. It was about my accented (brazilian portuguese) characters but I am not sure how i fixed it. But replacing accented characters with the equivalent one (ã -> a, for example) was a (bad) workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the charset that was being used when building the source map.

If you create an initializer file registering the mime type again with the charset setted to `:unicode` it will solve the problem:

`config/initializers/sprockets-register.rb`

`Sprockets.register_mime_type 'application/js-sourcemap+json', extensions: ['.js.map'], charset: :unicode`